# How can I ring my phone when it connects to WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, alarm

My WiFi has been spotty lately. I'm working from home, so this means work outages of 1-10 minutes every few days.

I would like to use my mobile phone as an alarm, so that when it reconnects to WiFi it will ring & let me know to get back to my desk.

Can it be done?

Comment: Other than a possibility of some focused 3rd-party apps, [general automation apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) might also help.

Comment: You many not want to depend on Android for this. Android goes into deep sleep to preserve battery all the time. At times I wake up my phone from deep sleep only to find it quickly reconnecting to a wifi, not because wifi signal was bad, but because of deep sleep. You "might get" false positives due to this deep sleep issue.